# Can ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier in Identity be null

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

In asp.net core, can the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier be null if a user has an Id?
(assuming the default settings are used)
Also, where does this value come from? I have a project using Identity framework
and although in the UserClaims table there are no such records(associating users with a NameIdentifier), the value is not null for the user currently logged in and I haven't written any code to manually assign this value to each user.

Comment: It cannot be null and comes from the source code this line:https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/05b2afb73b55b11d8cb3691dedfebba1f0285332/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs#L82

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.